# error in fetching data in nextjs13 with fetch method (Error: fetch failed)

Tags: node.js, next.js, next.js13

I use `Nextjs13` v13.4.4 with `Nodejs` v18.16.0 and sometimes when I run the page I got this error `Error: fetch failed` and When I log the error is see this error

```
Sliders TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: Error: read ECONNRESET
      at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
      at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    errno: -4077,
    code: 'ECONNRESET',
    syscall: 'read'
  }
}
- error TypeError: fetch failed
- error TypeError: fetch failed
digest: "2026204822"
```

this is my method to call the endpoint

```
import errorMessage from "../errorMessage.json";
import { MainSliderType } from "@/app/types/response/slider";
const serverUrl = process.env.SERVERURL;

export const mainSliderFetcher = async (): Promise<MainSliderType[]> => {
  try {
    const responses = await fetch(`${serverUrl}/sliders/`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      cache: "no-store",
    });

    if (!responses.ok) {
      throw new Error(errorMessage.fetchError);
    } else return responses.json();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("sliders", err);
    throw new Error(errorMessage.fetchError);
  }
};
```

and this is my `page.tsx` when calling this method.

```
export default async function Home() {
  const getSliders = mainSliderFetcher();
  const getBanners = mainBannersFetcher();

  const [sliders, banners] = await Promise.all([getSliders, getBanners]);

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center">
      <MainCarousel data={sliders} />
      <div className="flex flex-col px-4 lg:px-16">
        <TopBanners data={banners} />
        <SmallAbout />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

before I use `Nodejs` v16.08 and there I had the same issue

Comment: Is it related to the cache policy? If you setup to something else then `"no-store"`?

Comment: The serverurl is HTTPS?

Comment: @Peter yes is https

Comment: @Peter I don't know about cache policy. But I want fresh data and I must to use no-store

Comment: The next-app running in a docker container?

Comment: @Peter No. I just running in localhost

Comment: What is your nodejs version?

Comment: @Peter V18.16.0

Comment: Can you switch to nodejs 16 with nvm?

Comment: @Peter I did. With version 16.08 and 16.19 also. But same problem

Comment: What is your nextjs version?

Comment: @Peter nextjs v13.4.4

Comment: Can you downgrade it to 13.4.0?

Comment: @Peter No bcs the minimum node version is 16.08 for next13

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @AlirezaBagheri Actually no. but I think It's related to the server, not inside of Nextjs